# My iOS Swift App is Performing a Segue Regardless of Conditionals

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm creating an app using Parse. The flow of the app is simple: User signs up, if the signup is successful, perform a segue. If not, don't perform the segue. The problem is, the segue is happening regardless of my conditionals. Here's the code below.

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (succeeded: Bool!, signupError: NSError!) -> Void in
        if signupError == nil {
            // Hooray! Let them use the app now!
            println("Signed Up!")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegue", sender: self)
        } else {
            let errorString = signupError.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString
            // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
            println(errorString)
        }
    }
```

This is code directly from Parse documentation. I've also checked to see if looking at `succeeded != false` would work, too. It doesn't, lol.

Comment: Did you debug it? Are you sure that if an error exist the code will reach the else block?

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't added a segue in the storyboard which will be called if you press on the button? Because if that's the case, you need to remove it and you need to make a viewcontroller to viewcontroller segue. (Not a button to viewcontroller segue)

Comment: Why are you using `Bool!` in the block? Does changing it to `Bool` and testing against `succeeded` work?

Comment: @ChristianWoerz that was it. Total overlook on my part, thanks!

Comment: @traviswingo Glad to hear that. I've added it as an answer. Could you please accept it, so that other people can find it easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you haven't added a segue in the storyboard which will be called if you press on an `UIButton`?

Because if that's the case, you need to remove it and you need to make a `ViewController` to `ViewController` segue. (Not a `UIButton` to ViewController segue).